# Add or remove a class on two elements when two different events fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add/remove a class on the html and body tags in the dom when my nav menu is opened or closed. Is this the most optimal way of writing this logic?

```
$( '#navbarNav' ).on( 'show.bs.collapse', function() {
    $( 'html, body' ).addClass( 'noscroll' );
});

$( '#navbarNav' ).on( 'hide.bs.collapse', function() {
    $( 'html, body' ).removeClass( 'noscroll' );
});
```

Comment: It would be a good idea to mention that you are using Bootstrap, especially specifially which JS plugins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't repeat the queries. Store any queries that are called more than once in a variable, and utilize jQuery's chaining:

```
const navbarNav = $( '#navbarNav' );
const htmlBody = $( 'html, body' );

navbarNav.on( 'show.bs.collapse', function() {
    htmlBody.addClass( 'noscroll' );
}).on( 'hide.bs.collapse', function() {
    htmlBody.removeClass( 'noscroll' );
});
```

---

Why are you setting the class on both the `html` and `body` elements? Either should be sufficient.

---

Name the class [semantically](https://maintainablecss.com/chapters/semantics/). Just like you call a class for important text "`important`" and not "`red`", just because it happens to be red, you don't call a class that indicates whether the main navigation is open "`noscroll`" but "`main-nav-open`" (for example).